# HP Proliant DL160 No Power Meters detected?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

I've recently installed the hpasmcli on my ProLiant DL160 G6 and wanted to see what kind of power draw it was having.  However, when I try to use the `show powermeter` command, I get a "no power meters detected".

```
hpasmcli> show powermeter
No Power Meters were detected.

hpasmcli> show powersupply
Power supply #1
    Present  : Yes
    Redundant: No
    Condition: Ok
    Hotplug  : Not supported
```

My unit only has a single power supply in it, so I understand this output.

```
hpasmcli> show server
System        : ProLiant DL160 G6  
Serial No.    : USEXXXXX6L
ROM version   : O33 07/01/2013
iLo present   : No
```

Does the "no power meters detected" mean that my powersupply doesn't support that feature?  Is that what the `iLo present : No` means?  Is there a way to upgrade my power supply model to one that includes a power meter?  Is there a way to see the model number of the powersupply currently in my HP?

Comment: iLO is a controller to manage your server, its something else, so I assume your powersupply dont support that with the error you see

Comment: @yagmoth55 is there a way to see/validate ps model numbers and know which one(s) to but if I want a power supply with power meter support?

Comment: Iam not the best to answer, but usually in the 1xx serie in HP you lack management feature, as its their entry level server model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the "no power meters detected" mean that my powersupply doesn't support that feature?

This isn't feature of powersupply, this is feature of whatever connects PSUs to everything else - DL160 G6 doesn't have anything like that, it just has cables like typical computer (theoretically when you have one PSU, the PSU can measure power - but then there would have to be some extra connection to motherboard - there is none in given case).
So PSU can't give you that (no connection to rest with anything extra), and there is nothing between PSU and everything that can measure power.

> Is that what the `iLo present : No` means?

No, that means that you don't have iLo management in that server. DL160 G6 only has optional Lo100 management (that actually gives you access to voltages on all important rails, but not power measurement).

> Is there a way to upgrade my power supply model to one that includes a power meter?

AFAIK No. There isn't any PSU that supports that (since this isn't even PSU feature).

> Is there a way to see the model number of the powersupply currently in my HP?

Yes, there is sticker with part number and maximum wattage inside server on PSU itself. There is no way to do that with software, since AFAIK there is no information shared between PSU and motherboard (other than on-off like typical PC).

Answer (score 2):

This model is too low-end to provide the power meter monitoring functionality. This is a differentiating feature that is present in the HP ProLiant 300 and higher series.